# CMake unable to correctly link ultralight ui libraries to executable in Clion 2019.1.2

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion

Hi i'm trying to build a basic app using ultralight https://github.com/ultralight-ux/Ultralight. However the build is failing at the linking stage. I have gone through through a lot of other answers and not getting any progress.

The Cmake error:

```
C:/Users/AMWAJ-PC/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight3App6CreateEv'

C:/Users/AMWAJ-PC/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight6Window6CreateEPNS_7MonitorEjjbj'
C:/Users/AMWAJ-PC/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight7Overlay6CreateENS_3RefINS_6WindowEEEjjii'
C:/Users/AMWAJ-PC/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight6StringC1EPKc'
C:/Users/AMWAJ-PC/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight6StringD1Ev'
C:/Users/AMWAJ-PC/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight6StringD1Ev'
```

The Cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/C++/ultralight_ui/include/")
set(LINK_DIRS "C:/C++/ultralight_ui/lib/")
include_directories("${INCLUDE_DIRS}")
find_library(
    ULTRA_LIB
    NAMES UltralightCore AppCore Ultralight WebCore
    HINTS "${LINK_DIRS}")

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled1 ${ULTRA_LIB})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <AppCore/App.h>
#include <AppCore/Window.h>
#include <AppCore/Overlay.h>

using namespace ultralight;

int main()
{

auto app = App::Create();
auto window = Window::Create(app->main_monitor(), 300, 300, false, kWindowFlags_Titled);
window->SetTitle("Tutorial 2 - Basic App");
app->set_window(window);
auto overlay = Overlay::Create(window, window->width(), window->height(), 0, 0);
overlay->view()->LoadHTML("<center>Hello World!</center>");
app->Run();

return 0;
}
```

Any help will do great good to me :) Thank you

Comment: Is ultralib actually found by find_library? You could either make it REQUIRED or print out ${ULTRA_LIB} via message(${ULTRA_LIB}) or so. You probably should also not put hard coded absolute paths in a CMakeLists i think.

Comment: I'd recommend filing a feature request to ultralight to support cmake `find_package(UltraLight)` and exported target to ease useage.

Comment: Try printing the contents of `${ULTRA_LIB}` in your CMake file after calling `find_package`. This will show whether or not the variable was populated. Try this: `message(STATUS ${ULTRA_LIB})`

Comment: @squareskittles: `find_library` always populates the variable, either with the existed path to the library file, or with a `-NOTFOUND` value, which is never ignored by CMake (unlike to empty value). CMake may even warn when it finds `NOTFOUND` value used in the `target_link_libraries` call. Even without warning, the linker will emit an error about such values (because it cannot find the library with given name).

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly use `NAMES` parameter for `find_library`: this parameter contains list of **alternatives**, and `find_library` will result only with a *single library*, which has one of those names.

If you want several libraries to be found, you need to issue several `find_library` commands, each with its own name (and its own variable):

```
find_library(
    ULTRA_LIB_CORE
    NAMES UltralightCore
    HINTS ${LINK_DIRS})

find_library(
    ULTRA_LIB_APP_CORE
    NAMES AppCore
    HINTS ${LINK_DIRS})

find_library(
    ULTRA_LIB
    NAMES Ultralight
    HINTS ${LINK_DIRS})

find_library(
    ULTRA_LIB_WEB_CORE
    NAMES WebCore
    HINTS ${LINK_DIRS})

...

target_link_libraries(untitled1
    ${ULTRA_LIB_CORE} ${ULTRA_LIB_APP_CORE} ${ULTRA_LIB} ${ULTRA_LIB_WEB_CORE}
)
```

Comment: Then you probably miss some needed library. Or your libraries are **not compatible** with the compiler (e.g. libraries has been created for MinGW, and you attempt to use them with Visual Studio).

Comment: Yep @Tsyvarev the libraries were created for msvc and i tried to link it to mingw. The name mangling of c++ compiler were root of the error